# Replace occurrences of NSString with `'` to `\'`

Tags: ios, objective-c, replace, nsstring

I have a NSString in which I m trying to replace special characters. Part of my string looks like this:

I have replace `'` to `\'`

Comment: You could start by reviewing the spec for NSString.

Comment: This post shows no effort whatsoever in finding solution to your problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Note:** **\ is escape character in objective c.**

```
 NSString *s = @"This is Testing Mode and we are testing just Details of this Ladies' Market place";


NSString *r = [s stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@"\\'"];
```

Answer (score 12):

If you want to replace `'` with `\'` use

```
NSString *str = @"ladies'";
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@"\\'"];
```

`\` is an escape character so you'll have to use it twice.

Answer (score 4):

```
NSString *str = @"'Hello'";
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@"\\"];
```

Answer (score -1):

```
NSString *originalString = "a rand'om st'ring"
NSString *resultString = [originalString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@"\'"]; 


// "a random string" (output of "po resultString" in LLDB)
```

using the escape character "\", we can remove unwanted characters. The character next to escape character("\") will be ignored/escaped.

Comment: @Ronak, may be you are expecting `OriginalString` to be changed, you will get the trimmed string from the method's return type.